# How to create a single column with all the relevant text?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, compiler-errors, calculated-columns

I have a dataset [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll8yG.png) and I want to create a single column with a title and text. I tried to write a code like that:

```
df['text'] = df['title'] +" "+ df['text']

#Delete all the other columns.
  del df['title'] # added to text corpus
  del df['subject'] # it would affect results
  del df['date']
```

But it's not working and I get errors. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X4i3.png)

Comment: Can you do a `df.columns` and check if `title` has a space before or after it?

Comment: Also, a suggestion for future posts, just copy and paste the dataframe instead of adding an image :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the line you are looking for is:

```
df['new_text'] = df['title'].str.cat(df['text'],sep=" ")
```